# How to set infinite height with PaperSize using PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, printdocument

I'm following the guide:
[How to override Custom Papersize in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209126/how-to-override-custom-papersize-in-c-sharp)

But do not know how to set infinite height.
I am using a receipt printer.
How do I set an infinite height papersize?

```
_printerDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ?
```

I am able to print infinitely without this setting, but my width is off.
So I have to add Right Margins in order for the printing to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I was able to just set an "infinite" height just by adding a ridiculously large number.

```
_printerDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 285, 99999);
```

Comment: Passing [`int.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue) would set the `Height` as large as an `int` can represent.  Of course, "ridiculously large" and infinite aren't the same thing, though, for practical purposes, perhaps they are.